# Redirecting a page if user not logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

I'm building a web app that allows users to login with Facebook using OpenFB for Cordova.  I want only certain features viewable if they are logged in.  I am trying to run a check for login status and re-directing if not logged in.  This is what I have so far:

```
<head>
  <script>
    if(openFB.getLoginStatus.loginStatus = 'unknown'){
                    window.location ="#/app/home";
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

The getLoginStats function is as such:

```
function getLoginStatus(callback) {
    var token = tokenStore.fbAccessToken,
        loginStatus = {};
    if (token) {
        loginStatus.status = 'connected';
        loginStatus.authResponse = {accessToken: token};
    } else {
        loginStatus.status = 'unknown';
    }
    if (callback) callback(loginStatus);
}
```

When I console.log the value I am getting undefined. Even when logged in with facebook.  Am I missing something obvious?

Logout code requested:

```
//logout function
$scope.fbLogout = function(){
 openFB.logout(); //logouts after revoking permissions.
 alert('Logged out');
}
```

Comment: You using getLoginStatus as sync method. Maybe try to return {loginStatus : "someStatus"} from method.

Comment: The original FB.getLoginStatus method uses a cached result, you need to pass an additional parameter to make it circumvent the cache (see docs.) If that openFB thingie is just a wrapper for the official SDK methods(?), then it probably takes such a parameter as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openFB.getLoginStatus` is an asynchronous function that takes a callback as parameter. You have to use it like this:

```
openFB.getLoginStatus((loginStatus) => {
    console.log(loginStatus);
});
```

Comment: This looks good, but when i'm logged out I still get status = "connected"

Comment: it may be a caching issue. how exactly do you logout anyway? hopefully with openFB.logout()? try an api call with openFB.api after logout and see if you can get something. but don´t just call it right after logout, use the callback function of logout...that one is asynchronous too.

Comment: yes, openFB.logout() and then redirect after that.  Should I be revoking permissions as well?

Comment: i hope you don´t just redirect right after logout? are you using the callback function? no, you don´t need to revoke permissions if you just want to logout.

Comment: I was just using window.location.reload(); to refresh the page which I thought would update the loginStatus after logging out.

Comment: that was not my question...add your logout code in the question, that would be easier.

Comment: that is what i expected, you are not using the callback function as i told you to do: openFB.logout(() => {console.log('logged out');});

Comment: Still does not seem to be working. Login status is still "connected" after changing the logout.  I might try a different approach.